# Make HTTP requests without opening a new connection

Tags: javascript, http, tcp

If a browser opens a connection to a remote server, is it possible to access *that same connection* via Javascript?

I have a small Ethernet module on my network that I program sort of like this (pseudocode):

```
private var socket
while(true) {
    if(socket is disconnected) {
        open socket
        listen on socket (port 80)
    }
    if(connection interrupt) {
        connect socket
    }
    if(data receive interrupt) {
        serve
    }
    if(disconnection interrupt) {
        disconnect socket
    }
}
```

The point is that it listens on *one socket* for HTTP requests and serves them.

In my web browser, I can connect to the device, making an HTTP GET request for some HTML/JS that I've written, and it works. A connection is opened on the socket and the files come back as HTTP responses.

Now I want to click a button on the webpage and have the browser send an HTTP POST request over that same connection. In my Javascript, I have (edited and formatted for clarity):

```
// This function sends an HTTP request
function http(type, url, data, callbacks) {
    // make a new HTTP request
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // open a connection to the URL
    request.open(type, url + (data ? "?" + data : ""));

    // add headers
    if(type == "POST")
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // register callbacks for the request
    Object.keys(callbacks).forEach(function(callback) {
        request[callback] = function() {
            callbacks[callback](request.responseText);
        };
    });

    // send and return the request
    request.send();
    return request;
}

// Here is where I call the function
http("POST",                // use POST method
     "http://192.168.1.99", // IP address of the network device
     dataToSend,            // the data that needs to be sent
     {                      // callbacks
         onloadend: function(data) {
             console.log("success. got: " + data); // print 'success' when the request is done
         },
         onerror: function(data) {
             console.log("There was an error.");   // print 'error' when it fails
             console.log(data);
         }
     }
);
```

The issue here is that this *opens a new connection* to the device, but I want to use the same socket that the browser is already connected to. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I have figured out that opening a second socket (say, on port 81) and POSTing to `http://192.168.1.99:81` does work. However, I would still like to do this without opening a separate socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no application control inside the browser to decide if a new connection is used for the next request or if an existing connection is used. In fact, it is perfectly normal that the browser will use multiple connections in parallel to the same server and your server has to be able to deal with this.

Since your server architecture seems to be only able to deal with one connection at a time you either would need to change the architecture to handle multiple parallel connections or to make sure that you only need to handle a single connection at a time. The latter could be achieved by not supporting HTTP keep-alive, i.e. by closing the connection immediately after each response. This way a new request will result in a new connection (which is not what you wanted according to your question) but your server will also be able to handle this new connection (which is what you likely ultimately need) since the previous one was closed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It sounds like I either A) force the connection to close on the server side and then re-open the socket after every single transmission, or B) make sure there is always an extra socket open on the server side so that the browser has a place to send requests. Method A seems pretty reasonable, but could be inefficient maybe? (Doesn't sound like the way these connections are meant to be used.) Method B also sounds reasonable, but I am limited on sockets and how do I know when the browser will use one that's open vs. trying to use a new one?

Comment: @nullromo: with B) you don't only need a spare socket but usually multiple sockets (they often open 4 parallel connections) and you also need to be handle requests on these connections in parallel. A) is therefore much simpler but yes, it imposes the overhead of creating a new connection for each new request which is especially a problem if there is a higher latency between client and server.